# Vue-router API version 4 страница не отображается и выдаёт ошибку

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Новый маршрутизатор createRouter() не отображает страницу

Вроде бы прописал всё по новым требованиям, но страница не отображается и выдаёт ошибку.
Есть такой код
[image: Сам код]

Выдаёт такую ошибку
[image: Ошибка вывода]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)